DataGrid MUI and React Testing Libray - Test failed
I've created a react component on my app using DataGrid MUI component. I would like to test this component using React Testing Library. After executing my test, I've the following error :

MUI: useResizeContainer - The parent DOM element of the data grid has
an empty height. Please make sure that this element has an intrinsic
height. The grid displays with a height of 0px.

After many tries, I decided to test with the simplest component possible:
export default function DataGridDemo() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 350, width: 350 }}>
      <DataGrid
        columns={[{ field: 'id' }, { field: 'name' }]}
        rows={[
          { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' },
          { id: 2, name: 'Max Zander' },
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

Here is my test (failed :/ ) :
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import DataGridDemo from 'src/components/DataGridDemo';

    it('Test my DataGridDemo', async () => {
      render(<DataGridDemo />);
    });

I've seen many links and tips here, but I've always the same problem.
Details of libraries used:

"react": "18.2.0"
"@mui/material": "~5.15.5",
"@mui/x-data-grid": "~6.19.3"

What I've tried?

Using autoHeight MUI props in my component
Using disableVirtualization MUI props in my component (https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/virtualization/#disable-virtualization)
Using ResizeObserverMock in my test (ex : https://github.com/cherniavskii/data-grid-testing)
Change width and height of my component
Upgrade libs versions

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks a lot!
